# Trying to populate a column in a dataframe with values from another differently structured dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dataframes, orig_df and another_df.

orig_df:

```
year    colour      result

2004    red         NaN
2004    yellow      NaN
2005    yellow      NaN
2005    green       NaN
```

another_df:

```
            red     yellow  green   blue

2004        1.2     2.5     1.6     1.9
2005        1.8     NaN     1.7     2.0
2006        NaN     2.2     1.9     1.5
2007        1.0     NaN     NaN     0.8
```

What I am trying to do is populate the result column in `orig_df` with values from `another_df`. Specifically, in the `orig_df` row that has year 2005 and colour green I want to place the corresponding value from `another_df` where the row has year 2005 and the column is green (in this case the value 1.7)
The only way I could come up with for solving this was to access individual values in `another_df` by using `loc[index, column]` and passing values from `orig_df` to it but it doesn't work as I expected it to.

For example doing something like this works just fine:

```
orig_df['result'] = orig_df.year
```

The end result looks like this:

```
year    colour      result

2004    red         2004
2004    yellow      2004
2005    yellow      2005
2005    green       2005
```

This works too:

```
orig_df['result'] = orig_df.colour
```

In both cases it will take the proper value from the same row and populate everything without any issues.

But when I try to do this:

```
orig_df['result'] = another_df.loc[orig_df.year, orig_df.colour]
```

all hell breakes loose. 
What I believe is happening is that instead of having just the year value from the current row, orig_df.year now holds all the values contained in orig_df column 'year', all at once. I know I am probably overcomplicating things but I have no clue how to go about this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need first reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` with `MultiIndex` and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for new column by `year` and `colour`:

```
s = another_df.stack().rename('result')
print (s)
2004  red       1.2
      yellow    2.5
      green     1.6
      blue      1.9
2005  red       1.8
      green     1.7
      blue      2.0
2006  yellow    2.2
      green     1.9
      blue      1.5
2007  red       1.0
      blue      0.8
Name: result, dtype: float64

#if thre is column result first remove it
df = orig_df.drop('result', axis=1).join(s, on=['year','colour'])
print (df)
   year  colour  result
0  2004     red     1.2
1  2004  yellow     2.5
2  2005  yellow     NaN
3  2005   green     1.7
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just a quick follow-up question. Any clue as to why my version would not work? I know it's probably greatly inefficient, but I still don't understand why it didn't work as expected, from a technical point of view. Why in one case it would take the value from one row at a time and in another it would just try to dump all values, from all rows at once. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! So in pandas `another_df.loc[orig_df.year, orig_df.colour]` does not work, because it return another DataFrame, not new column.